# Installing virtualenv 20.0.33 on a webhost without root access

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

All similar questions and instructions I have found, are for versions up to 16.2.0. I tried using the instructions from 16.2.0 The file used to install, was pypa-virtualenv-YYYYY/src/virtualenv.py but version 20.0.33 does not contain the file virtualenv.py.

I can't find any other newer instructions where there is no pip, no pipx, no easy_install and no root access. Is it still possible? Is there perhaps a different method?

I want to use django in a virtual environment. My webhost will not install django nor do they support it but if I can manage to do so without root access, they appear OK with me doing so.

Comment: what is your python version? are u trying to install it on web server? or local machine?

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't find any other newer instructions where there is no pip, no pipx, no easy_install and no root access. Is it still possible?" do you want to install it without pip, pipx or easy_install?

Comment: It's on a web server and the python version is 2.7. I've asked why they don't have python 3 installed and they say it is coming. 

Previously you could install it without pip, pipx or easy_install by following these instructions.

$ curl -L -o virtualenv.tar.gz https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/X.X.X
$ tar xfz virtualenv.tar.gz
$ python pypa-virtualenv-YYYYY/src/virtualenv.py env

Comment: so did you resolve your issue? if yes, you should edit your question to be clear, for example how to install virtualenv version 20.0.33 from source for python2.7.